# How to define functions for specific variants

Tags: rust, enums, pattern-matching, dispatch

I have an `enum` with an associated `show` function.

```rust
enum Foo {
    Bar(u32),
    Baz
}

fn show(foo: Foo) {
    match foo {
        Foo::Bar(_) => show_bar(foo),
        Foo::Baz => show_baz(foo),
    }
}
```

Based on the variant, a specialized `show_*` function is called.

```rust
fn show_bar(foo: Foo) {
    match foo {
        Foo::Bar(x) => println!("BAR({x})"),
        _ => (),
    }
}

fn show_baz(foo: Foo) {
    match foo {
        Foo::Baz => println!("BAZ"),
        _ => (),
    }
}
```

Since I can't pass variants as types, I need to repeat the `match foo` pattern matching inside each `show_*` function, which is a bit verbose and undeeded.

Is there a better / more idiomatic way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

I'm a fairly simple soul and not a Rust expert, so maybe this doesn't meet your needs for some reason - but why not simply pass the associated data? (Which is nothing in the case of `Baz`)

```
enum Foo {
    Bar(u32),
    Baz
}

fn show(foo: Foo) {
    match foo {
        Foo::Bar(barValue) => show_bar(barValue),
        Foo::Baz => show_baz(),
    }
}

fn show_bar(x: u32) {
    println!("BAR({x})"),
}

fn show_baz() {
    println!("BAZ"),
}
```